# Inkscape: subscript of superscript / superscript of subscript

Tags: inkscape, text

Is it possible to create subscripts in superscripts, e.g., “10<sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup>”?
(The expression with LaTeX would be `10^{a_{1}}`)
[image]

Comment: Note that Inkscape (usually) comes with a TeX renderer.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to use the vertical kerning. Select the letter, then press spacing and adjust the vertical kerning (negative values: shift up, positive values: shift down):

[image: A screenshot of the spacing menu]

The following is a short demonstration:

[image: a short GIF animation demonstrating how to use vertical kerning to emulate subscripts]